# LDAP over SSL 636, works locally but not externally

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap

I've currently set-up a VM with an AD, CS & LDAP Server. I've done some configuration so that everything works internally, however, this doesn't seem to work when attempting to access the machine externally.

On the First Machine, locally, i can use ldp.exe and connect with SSL over the 636 port.

With the second machine, on the same network, i attempt to connect over the 636 port and the connection fails. However, the non-SSL 389 port still is able to connect.

Can anyone point out anything which may be causing this?

NOTE: I'm a developer, not a networking/sysadmin guy, so keep it simple please.

Thanks in advance, Jordan

EDIT:

This is the **netstat** for the 389 & 636 ports on TCP:

// Local?

- 0.0.0.0:389 / 0.0.0.0:0 / LISTENING
- 0.0.0.0:636 / 0.0.0.0:0 / LISTENING

// Not sure...

- [::]:389 / [::]:0 / LISTENING
- [::]:636 / [::]:0 / LISTENING

// Also not sure, IP6?

- [fe90:11ee..............]:389 / [fe90:11ee..............]:60441 / ESTABLISHED
- [fe90:11ee..............]:389 / [fe90:11ee..............]:60445 / ESTABLISHED
- [fe90:11ee..............]:389 / [fe90:11ee..............]:60449 / ESTABLISHED

**WINDOWS FIREWALL** is turned off, so i think the rule's wouldn't be an issue.

**ERROR**

ld = ldap_sslinit("ldaptest.local", 636, 1);

Error 0 = ldap_set_option(hLdap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

Error 81 = ldap_connect(hLdap, NULL);

Server error:

Error <0x51>: Fail to connect to ldaptest.local.

Comment: locally, run "netstat -an" to see lines containing :389 and :636, it will tell us if you are listening on localhost or host IP. If port 636 is like 389 on the host ip, this means the firewall is blocking.

Comment: you can add a Windows firewall port exception rule for port 389, 636

Comment: If the above comments haven't solved the problem, also post exactly how "the connection fails", including the error message(s) you get.  Does the TCP connection attempt simply time out?  Is it refused?  Do you get an SSL error?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Updated the post to answer your question

Comment: Do you have access to a telnet client (or some other networking client like `nc`)?  If so, try something like `telnet ldaptest.local 636` to see if you can do a raw TCP connect to the LDAP server.  Can you also post details about the certificate your LDAP server is using for SSL?   There are a few places it could be failing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle hey, i installed telnet on the server and my local machine. Telnet on the server gives me a blinking cursor (which i understand is saying it is connected) and my local machine shows only a non-blinking cursor (but no error message). 

As for the CERT details, can you be more specific, i merely followed a guide for issuing an SSL cert with the AD CS server. The issuer is the only information i see any real value in, CN=ldaptest-LDAPTEST-CA, DC=ldaptest, DC=local, it's valid & issued by the same machine which issued it, and is intended for issuance & application policies.